# Add new element in result Fetchrow without use of toArray

Tags: php, zend-framework

My request with zend 1 :

```
$table_mail = Table_Factory::getInstance()->getTable('Table_Dossier');
$req = $table_mail->select()->where('id_email =?', $id_email);
$data_email = $table_mail->fetchRow($req);
```

$data_email contains :

```
 object(Zend_Db_Table_Row)[75]
  protected '_data' => 
    array (size=17)
      'id_email' => string '1685' (length=4)
      'id_operation' => string '931' (length=3)
```

...

But after i want add one element (to_moi) in $data_email (without use of toArray()).
I have try without success :

```
$data_email[] = array('to_moi' => true);
$data_email->put('to_moi' , true);
$data_email->to_moi = true;
$data_email(array('to_moi' => true));
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this will may help you ,

```
$data_email['to_moi'] = true;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but i have always the error : Specified column "to_moi" is not in the row

Comment: can you please put output of your $data_email.